# Why we create multiple objects in same class in oop?

Tags: php, oop, object

I am trying to learn oop, but not understand the concept of why we use same class for multiple objects?

```
class mobiles
{
    public $name;
    public $price;
    public $wifi;
}

$obj_nokia = new mobiles();
$obj_samsung = new mobiles();
```

Comment: because in your example, nokia and samsung are both "mobiles", and thus share the same properties and methods?

Comment: because multiple objects has same attributes and same functionalities. for example 2 or more cars have same attributes and functionalities (car is an object and `fuel`, `max_speed` is an attributes and `getFuel()`, `getSpeed()` is functionalities ) . as per your example nokia and samsung have same attributes like name, price and wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because multiple objects has same attributes and same functionalities.

for example 2 or more cars have same attributes and functionalities (car is an object and `fuel`, `max_speed` is an attributes and `getFuel()`, `getSpeed()` is functionalities ) .

As per your example nokia and samsung have same attributes like `name`, `price` and `wifi`. `obj_nokia` and `obj_samsung` is an object with same attributes and these objects belongs to same class (`mobiles`).

so, i can't create car object like `$car_ferrari = new mobiles();` because `car_ferrari` object not belongs with mobiles class

The better way: you think about real world objects and it's class